# Docker containers freezing

Tags: node.js, docker, containers, freeze

I'm currently trying to deploy a node.js app on docker containers. I need to deploy 30 of them but they begin to have a weird behavior at some point, some of them freeze.

I am currently running **Docker version for windows 18.03.0-ce, build 0520e24302**, my computer specs (cpu and memory):

> - I5 4670 K
> - 24 GB of ram

**My docker default machine resource allocation is the following :**

> - Allocated RAM : 10 Gb
> - Allocated vCPUs : 4

My node application is running on **apline3.8** and **node.js 11.4** and mostly do http requests every 2-3 seconds.

When i try to deploy 20 containers everything is running like a charm, my application do the job and i can see that there is an activity on every on my containers through the logs, activity stats.

The problem comes when i try to deploy more containers, more than 20, i can notice that some of the previously deployed containers start to stop their activities (0% cpu using, logs freezing). When everything is deployed (30 containers), Docker start to block the activity of some of them and unblock them at some point to block some others (blocking/unblocking is random). It seems to be sequential. I tried to wait and see what happened and the result is that some of the containers are able to poursue their activities and some others are stuck forever (still running but no more activity).

It's important to **notice that i used the following resources restrictions on each of my containers :**

> - MemoryReservation : 160mb
> - Memory soft limit : 160mb
> - NanoCPUs : 250000000 (0.25 cpus)

I had to increase my docker default machine resource allocation and decrease container's ressource allocation because it was using almost 100% of my cpu, maybe i did a mistake in my configuration. I tried to tweak those values, but no success i still have some containers freezing.

I'm kind of lost right know.

Any help would be appreciated even a little one, thank you in advance !

Comment: It seems, the load is simply too high for your machine.

Comment: Thank you @Henry for the reply, i was thinking the same but at idle (for 20 containers) it doesn't reach more than 25% of my Cpu. I could be able to put more charge. Unless this percentage is altered by something else.

Comment: Is this using Docker for Mac? Docker for Windows?

Comment: @maxm I edited the question, it's on windows with virtualbox

Comment: Just a shot in the dark but how many ports do you have open?

Comment: You use both --memory and --memoryReservation right? Just reminding you, soft limit is actually given by --memoryReservation and --memory is the hard limit. 

Also, are these all the same application? If so, deploying onto a swarm as service and replicating could be a better approach. If they are all different applications, maybe the ones that are deployed after the first 20 could require more resources causing a deadlock somehow.

In any case, docker on Windows has tons of problems :/

Comment: And, about virtualbox, what are the allocated CPUs? Does it mean %100 affinity Or virtual CPUs? As you assign nanoCPUs to docker, they require 0.25 * 20 = 5 CPUs in total, and not 4. Virtualbox threading -might- be (i am not familiar with virtualbox) implemented badly and fails when the total usage exceeds 4 CPUs.

Comment: @maxm My application doesn't expose/publish any ports if that is what you mean

Comment: @YamaçKurtuluş Thank you for you reply, i use both so the memory allocation should be locked a the same value right which means a fixed value? i might be wrong in the configuration. i thought about swarm but yes they are all different so it might be the case.

I gave 4 vCpus to virtualbox, and you're right my nano cpus allocation is wrong, and as you said the overconsuming/bad handling might be a matter of misconfiguration, i'll make some new tests and reallocate correctly the resources and see what's happening, thank you !

Comment: @YamaçKurtuluş After some tests even with decreasing nanoCpus allocation (0.12 - 0.11 - 0.10) the behavior is still the same :/ I might reconsider my way to deploy them and maybe use docker swarm or other docker agents

Comment: I suggest trying it on the host machine just to see what happens.